# Making a local database accessible online

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am making this Student Information System for my Thesis, and I am doing it in local phpserver. What I want it to be accessible online and locally from other PC's that is connected in Local Area Network. Can someone enlighten me.

PS: I only have done is a wordpress webpage before .

Comment: You could make the local webserver on your machine accessible from other machines in your local network - but of course then your machine must be on at all times that people might want to use the site, and it will consume some CPU on your machine when they do. Alternatively you can ask if your school/college has a shared server running PHP and MySQL where you can upload a copy of your site. Your last option is to see if you can find some free hosting online with a hosting service provider. Sometimes you can get free accounts although they are not always very reliable, and generally full of ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On your database server, as a user with root privileges, open your MySQL configuration file.

To locate it, enter the following command:

mysql --help

The location displays similar to the following:

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

On Ubuntu 16, the path is typically

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.
```

2. Search the configuration file for bind-address.

If it exists, change the value as follows.

If it doesn’t exist, add it anywhere except the [mysqld] section.

bind-address =

See MySQL documentation, especially if you have a clustered web server.

3. Save your changes to the configuration file and exit the text editor.
4. Restart the MySQL service:

- CentOS: service mysqld restart
- Ubuntu: service mysql restart

```
GRANT ALL ON <local database name>.* TO <remote web node username>@<remote web node server ip address> IDENTIFIED BY '<database user password>';
```

Comment: We we're asked to use a cloud server , but this will be a big help in the future. Thanks a lot.